# SQL Query: Grouping the latest messages using SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the **latest** messages about **each** post from different users using SQL. I have 3 tables:

- The Users Table (To collect user Information)
- The Post Table (To Collect post information)
- The Messages Table (Table containing messages)

However, I am getting an error with my SQL Syntax, Here is the code

```
SELECT
   MAX(sequence) AS latestmsg,
   COUNT(*) AS msgcount,
   sequence,
   messageid,
   username,
   receipient,
   message,
   datestamp 
FROM
   messages 
   JOIN
      users 
      ON messages.username = users.username 
   JOIN
      posts 
      ON posts.postid = messages.messageid 
WHERE
   messages.receipient = 'try-2a' 
GROUP BY
   messages.messageid 
ORDER BY
   messages.sequence DESC
```

**Error: Column 'username' in field list is ambiguous**

[Link to Fiddle with Schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/279c0e/3)

Comment: Please check the link to SQLfiddle. You can modify the query and run it against my schema.

Comment: Which dbms is this?????

Comment: The error is very clear.  Column is ambiguous.  The column `username` exists in both table, so in your select, put `messages.username` or `users.username` to make not ambiguous.

Comment: I am using Phpmyadmin

Comment: Then add tag `mysql` to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
       MAX(sequence) AS latestmsg,
       COUNT(*) AS msgcount,
       sequence,
       messageid,
       users.username,
       receipient,
       message,
       datestamp 
    FROM
       messages 
       JOIN
          users 
          ON messages.username = users.username 
       JOIN
          posts 
          ON posts.postid = messages.messageid 
    WHERE
       messages.receipient = 'try-2a' 
    GROUP BY
       messages.messageid 
    ORDER BY
       messages.sequence DESC
```

Try the modified query below:

```
SELECT sequence AS latestmsg,
    msgcount,
    sequence,
    messages.messageid,
    users.username,
    receipient,
    message,
    messages.datestamp 
FROM messages 
JOIN users ON messages.username = users.username 
JOIN posts ON posts.postid = messages.messageid 
JOIN (
    SELECT messageid, MAX(sequence) AS max_seq, COUNT(*) AS msgcount
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY messageid
) m ON m.messageid = messages.messageid AND m.max_seq = messages.sequence
WHERE messages.receipient = 'try-2a' 
ORDER BY messages.sequence DESC
```

Comment: This solves the error. But the grouping is still not what i intended. I am relatively new to mySQL so pardon me. I would like to query the messages grouped by the messageid and the username. So that only the latest message per user relating each post is displayed.

Comment: How do identify latest message?  Highest messageid?

Comment: The latest message from each user can be identified by the sequence of the message in the database or the datestamp.

Answer (score 0):

The `username` column in the `SELECT` list needs to have the table alias prefixed, since `username` exists in both `messages` and `users`

```
SELECT
   MAX(sequence) AS latestmsg,
   COUNT(*) AS msgcount,
   sequence, 
   messageid,
   username, --This column needs to have the alias prefix
   receipient,
   message,
   datestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the most recent message for each user, you would want to group by user, then find the max timestamp of each message in each user group. You can use that to then select the message with that timestamp matching it.

Comment: I tried coming up with query to match your answer but I was not getting the appropriate output. could you help generate a query? would be helpful to me and others that will view this post later.